# Unit test import method jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using [clone package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone) in my angular app and I am writing unit test for test() method of class abc.

**abc.ts**

```
Import * as clone from clone;
class abc {
    test(){
        const clone= clone(this);
        if (clone){
            // success logic
        }else{
            // unsuccess logic
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write jasmine test case to test the unsuccessful scenario i.e clone fail scenario.
I am unable to spyOn the clone method of the clone npm package.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the clone method in your abc class. 
spyOn(instanceOfAbc, "cloneWrap")